# On page reload, open to a specific accordion panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, reload, jquery-ui-accordion

From an accordion panel, I post some data and then reload the page.  I'd like on the reload for the current panel to be open and focused on the screen rather than re-opening the first panel and moving me back to the top of the screen.  I know which panel I want open, so I don't need code to figure out the panel, just how to display it.

```
 $.post('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Contract/AddContractLocation") %>', $(form).serialize(), function (data) {
         if (data.Result == "success") {
              ... yada yada... 
              window.location.reload();
         }
```

**Edit to Add:**

This is how I initialize the accordion:

```
$("#acc").accordion({
         autoHeight: false,
         navigation: true
});
```

This is the basic structure:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contract</legend>

    <div id="acc">
        <h3><a href="#contractinfo">Contract Info</a></h3>
        <div>
            stuff
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#locationandrs">Locations and Ratesheets</a></h3>   
        <div>
            stuff
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#auditibleterms">Auditable Terms</a></h3>
        <div>
            stuff
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#contractdocs">Contract Docs</a></h3>
        <div>
            stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time back in this code in about a year, and while I was working on something else was able to figure this out.

```
var substr = window.location.href.split('#'); 
window.location.href = substr[0] + "#locationandrs";
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you set the [active](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active) option to true on the returned value? You need to click on 'options' from the link but here's the docs:

> Selector for the active element. Set
>   to false to display none at start.
>   Needs collapsible: true. Code examples
>
> Initialize a accordion with the active
>   option specified.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
> ```
>
> Get or set the active option, after
>   init.
>
> ```
> //getter
> var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
> //setter
> $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
> ```

Comment: If I set that right before my reload, it still reloads with the first panel open.

Comment: I added `$("#acc").accordion("option", "active", 3);` before the `window.location.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

On submitting form send hidden parameter, identifying open panel. You get this parameter and using it assign special id to appropriate panel during outputting  HTML code. Then init accordion in js-script:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({ 
   ...
   ,active: '#panel_selected'
   ...
});
$('#panel_selected').get(0).scrollIntoView(false); // scroll until panel is visible
```

That's all!